# EmguCV missing dll

Tags: c#, winforms, opencv, dll, emgucv

i've started with EmguCV and there is a problem. According to documentation downloaded NuGet package with EmguCV and write some code. Win form app debugging and running correct but shape recognition doesn't work(never appear). Then i've noticed information in console (details in the picture). After download Nuget i have references: Emgu.CV.UI, Emgu.CV.World.NetStandard and ZedGraph.

My Question is what should download to make this work. Does EmguCV need OpenCV Nuget package to?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiBah.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Antivirus blocked some parts of Nuget package. After disabled antivirus, package download properly and everything is fine.